# ML Console application throwing native dll not found error

Tags: ml.net

I created one Dotnet core application using VS 2017 and then published it and then copied the published folder having runtimes folder and my application dll to Windows server 2016 where I had installed the dotnet core framework.

Even time I run the application from command line I get the below error. (I found this dll is under the runtimes folder but somehow application is not able to load)

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.DllNotFoundException:
>   Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative' or one of its dependencies: The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

Answer (score 1):

My server was missing this VCRuntime140.DLL and I had to install

> Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017